# How to install skdet for rkhunter for Performing Suckit Rookit additional checks?

Tags: rkhunter

*OS: Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon 64-bit*

Although I don't use the `rkhunter` much, probably several times a year, today I decided to look at it.

I found in `rkhunter` log:

```
/var/log/rkhunter.log
```

that it seems to lack some `skdet` binary in the following section:

```
Performing Suckit Rookit additional checks
```

where it states, that:

```
Running skdet command                         [ Skipped ]
Info: Unable to find the 'skdet' command
```

Since there's no available package under this name, I wonder what it actually is, and quite frankly, how to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not available in packaged version, since having an unclear license, and **its use is limited to your own risk** as stated [here](https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-security-team/rkhunter/blob/debian/master/debian/README.Debian#L108).

I have found it be hosted on some strangely named domain:

https://dvgevers.home.xs4all.nl/skdet/

And since I don't know if it will always be available there, I have just hosted it on my domain, untouched, see below backup link, if the originals ever become broken in time.

First, make some directory for the files.

There are three files you will need:

- [skdet-1.0.tar.bz2](https://dvgevers.home.xs4all.nl/skdet/skdet-1.0.tar.bz2)
- [skdet-1.0.sha1](https://dvgevers.home.xs4all.nl/skdet/skdet-1.0.sha1)
- [skdet-fix-includes.diff](https://dvgevers.home.xs4all.nl/skdet/skdet-fix-includes.diff)

More conveniently, you can use e.g. `wget` to download them directly from your terminal:

(New 2022-Nov-18) backup link for all files:

```
https://www.vlastimilburian.cz/public/skdet.tar
```

Download them all to that directory you've created.

Extract the `bzip`'ed file:

```
tar -xjf skdet-1.0.tar.bz2
```

It will expand one directory named `skdet-1.0`.

Move the `diff` file into that directory:

```
mv skdet-fix-includes.diff skdet-1.0/
```

Edit the `sha1` file, so that the last line:

```
59bfb29bc1f7601027629453a39dc81508dd9df5 skdet-1.0/skdet-fix-includes.diff
```

has 2 spaces between the hash and file name, otherwise it would be skipped.

Then, let's check the integrity of those files:

```
sha1sum --check skdet-1.0.sha1
```

All should be OK.

Now, we need to apply the patch file:

```
cd skdet-1.0/
patch -p 1 < skdet-fix-includes.diff
```

It will say:

```
patching file src/skdet.c
patching file src/usage.c
```

We don't need the `diff` file now:

```
rm skdet-fix-includes.diff
```

Though it already contains the binary pre-compiled, I rather compile myself, so...

```
make clean
```

Let's compile this thing already:

```
make
```

It will output one file named `skdet`.

Just copy it where you like to have your own compiled binaries, for me:

```
sudo cp skdet /usr/local/bin/
```

And you're basically done.

Just update your `rkhunter`'s file properties database and virus database files:

```
sudo rkhunter --propupd
sudo rkhunter --update
```

Finally, after your `rkhunter` command, for example:

```
sudo rkhunter --check --enable all --disable none --skip-keypress
```

Should result into such entry in the log file:

```
sudo cat /var/log/rkhunter.log | grep -B 6 -A 1 "skdet command"

[16:23:13] Performing additional rootkit checks
[16:23:13]
[16:23:13]   Performing Suckit Rookit additional checks
[16:23:13]     Checking hard link count on '/sbin/init'      [ OK ]
[16:23:13]     Checking for hidden file extensions           [ None found ]
[16:23:13] Info: Found the 'skdet' command: /usr/local/bin/skdet
[16:23:13]     Running skdet command                         [ OK ]
[16:23:13]   Suckit Rookit additional checks                 [ OK ]
```

Voilà!